# Javascript - sort Array by reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, opengl-es, reference

I'm trying to sort a JavaScript Array by the reference to another object.

I have An array of Mesh. Each mesh contains an attribute named "**texture**", which contains the reference to a WebGLTexture object.
WebGLTexture objects doesn't contains any readable attribute, I can only compare it by reference (`==`). toString method isn't defined.

Here is an example of the initial situation :

```
var texture1 = gl.createTexture(/* blah */); // Returns a WebGLTexture object
var texture2 = gl.createTexture(/* blah */); // Returns a WebGLTexture object
var texture3 = gl.createTexture(/* blah */); // Returns a WebGLTexture object
var meshes = [
    {name: "Mesh 0", texture: texture1},
    {name: "Mesh 1", texture: texture2},
    {name: "Mesh 2", texture: texture3},
    {name: "Mesh 3", texture: texture3},
    {name: "Mesh 4", texture: texture2},
    {name: "Mesh 5", texture: texture1},
    {name: "Mesh 6", texture: texture1},
    {name: "Mesh 7", texture: texture2},
    {name: "Mesh 8", texture: texture3},
    {name: "Mesh 9", texture: texture1}
];
```

What I want to do is to sort the array by texture reference, to have something like this (the order is not really important, I just want the object which have the same texture to be consecutive) :

```
var meshes = [
    {name: "Mesh 0", texture: texture1},
    {name: "Mesh 5", texture: texture1},
    {name: "Mesh 6", texture: texture1},
    {name: "Mesh 9", texture: texture1},
    {name: "Mesh 1", texture: texture2},
    {name: "Mesh 4", texture: texture2},
    {name: "Mesh 7", texture: texture2},
    {name: "Mesh 2", texture: texture3},
    {name: "Mesh 3", texture: texture3},
    {name: "Mesh 8", texture: texture3}
];
```

I know it could be possible to achieve it with loops, but It will require to create objects and arrays, and to do many nested loops. Performance is really important here.

The best solution I can found is to manually add a unique "id" attribute to each texture, and use Array.sort on it. But I'm not really happy with this solution it implies to modify native objects.

Do you know any native and fast method ?

EDIT : Based on wared answer, here is the solution :

```
var tempSortTextures = [];
meshes.sort(function(a, b) {
    var iA = null;
    var iB = null;
    for(var i = 0 ; i <= tempSortTextures.length ; i++) {
        if(i == tempSortTextures.length) {
            if(iA == null) {
                tempSortTextures.push(a.texture);
            } else /*if(iB == null)*/ {
                tempSortTextures.push(b.texture);
            }
        }
        var currentTexture = tempSortTextures[i];
        if(iA == null && a.texture == currentTexture) iA = i;
        if(iB == null && b.texture == currentTexture) iB = i;
        if(iA != null && iB != null) return iA - iB;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why did someone downvoted this two months after ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the best solution but it works (with pure javascript) :)

```
var map = [texture1, texture2, texture3];

meshes.sort(function (a, b) {
    var i = 0, item;
    while (item = map[i]) {
        if (a.texture && item === a.texture) { a = i; }
        if (b.texture && item === b.texture) { b = i; }
        if (!a.texture && !b.texture) { return a - b; }
        i++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Looping into the sort function, and just over the textures list is a good idea. I'll do something like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is a built-in solution for that.

You cannot use `Array.sort()` unless you can define an ordering relation on your objects, e.g. implement an operation `<=`.  JavaScript does not expose meta information such as memory addresses, so there is no non-obtrusive solution.

As always, "fast" is a relative term.  There is no "absolute fast", only "fast enough", so a naive `O(n^2)` implementation might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing the sorting using the new experimental [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) (only supported in Firefox as of this writing). By associating each texture with an index with the help of a WeakMap we can use the index in the sort function:

```
var texture1 = {name:"tex1"};
var texture2 = {name:"tex2"};
var texture3 = {name:"tex3"};

var meshes = [
    {name: "Mesh 0", texture: texture1},
    {name: "Mesh 1", texture: texture2},
    {name: "Mesh 2", texture: texture3},
    {name: "Mesh 3", texture: texture3},
    {name: "Mesh 4", texture: texture2},
    {name: "Mesh 5", texture: texture1},
    {name: "Mesh 6", texture: texture1},
    {name: "Mesh 7", texture: texture2},
    {name: "Mesh 8", texture: texture3},
    {name: "Mesh 9", texture: texture1}
];

var textureSortOrder = [texture1, texture2, texture3];
var sortMap = new WeakMap();

for (var i=0;i<textureSortOrder.length;i++) {
    sortMap.set(textureSortOrder[i], i);
}

meshes = meshes.sort(function(a, b){
   var indexA = sortMap.get(a.texture);
   var indexB = sortMap.get(b.texture);

    if (indexA < indexB) {
        return -1;
    } else if (indexA > indexB) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});

console.log("sorted:");
for (var i=0;i<meshes.length;i++) {
    console.log(i, meshes[i].texture.name);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ch5QJ/

I have no idea how fast this is, and as I said only Firefox supports WeakMap. But it might be worth testing it and use it for browsers which do support it if it does turn out to be fast.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I didn't know the maps in ES 6, that's good to know. It's a shame that it's not currently supported everywhere. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore for this. Which anyway i suggest you to include if you need to manipulate objects, make your life easier:

here there is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pmcalabrese/2KSSn/

and here the code.

```
sorted = _(meshes).sortBy(function(meshes) {
    return meshes.texture;
});
```

I suggest you to give a look at the documentation of sortBy.

Comment: I haven't used underscore, but I can't see how this will sort native objects correctly?

Comment: go to the js fiddle and then open the console of your browser you can see the result there.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I don't want/need to use any framework. And I looked at the source code of "_.sortBy" method : it will be slower than the slower solution that I thought about (loops).

Comment: It would be nice when/if you write a your solution to give a shot against underscore sortBy method. You can use http://jsperf.com/ for run the test ... so you can show me a better way to do it.

Comment: @pm.calabrese: But if I change the texture values from strings to `{name:"something1"}` it no longer sorts?

Comment: you need to use the same key so if you use name ---> then you need to change it in name and not texture. I suggest you one more time to visit the documentation on underscore website.

Comment: Name attribute is only for the example (to be able to visually identify the objects). There are no names in my application.

Comment: You mean if you change the entire string in a key/value pair  {name:"something1"}? But that's another thing of course does not sort. The code i provided it works for the example you provided. If you change the structure of the object you need to change the code accordingly.

Comment: @pm.calabrese, it looks like _.sortBy only sorts based on string or number comparison, which doesn't work since OP is asking for sorting by comparing WebGLTexture objects.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? I haven't done any performance testing.

Javascript

```
function sortByTextureOrderOrGroupThem (theArray, theOrder) {
    var temp = [],
        thisOrder = theOrder || [],
        thisOrderLength = thisOrder.length,
        thisOrderIndex,
        order,
        theArrayLength,
        theArrayIndex,
        element;

    // if we were given an order then build the temp array from that and remove the element from theArray
    for (thisOrderIndex = 0; thisOrderIndex < thisOrderLength; thisOrderIndex += 1) {
        order = thisOrder[thisOrderIndex];
        for (theArrayIndex = theArray.length - 1; theArrayIndex >= 0; theArrayIndex -= 1) {
            element = theArray[theArrayIndex];
            if (element.texture === order) {
                temp.push(theArray.splice(theArrayIndex, 1)[0]);
            }
        }
    }

    // anything remaining in the array, group them together
    theArray.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.texture === b.texture) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (a.texture < b.texture) {
            return -1;
        }

        return 1;
    });

    // join any remaining grouped items to the temp
    temp = temp.concat(theArray);
    // empty theArray
    theArray.length = 0;
    // add the length and the starting index for use with apply
    temp.unshift(temp.length);
    temp.unshift(0);
    // splice temp back into theArray
    [].splice.apply(theArray, temp);

    // return theArray in case it is needed this way
    return theArray;
}

var texture1 = {"name": "texture1"},
    texture2 = {"name": "texture2"},
    texture3 = {"name": "texture3"},
    meshes = [
        {name: "Mesh 0", texture: texture1},
        {name: "Mesh 1", texture: texture2},
        {name: "Mesh 2", texture: texture3},
        {name: "Mesh 3", texture: texture3},
        {name: "Mesh 4", texture: texture2},
        {name: "Mesh 5", texture: texture1},
        {name: "Mesh 6", texture: texture1},
        {name: "Mesh 7", texture: texture2},
        {name: "Mesh 8", texture: texture3},
        {name: "Mesh 9", texture: texture1}
    ],
    order = [texture1, texture2, texture3];

sortByTextureOrderOrGroupThem(meshes, order);
console.log(JSON.stringify(meshes));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/fHbPP/)

Comment: That seems like the first solution I thought at first, but I'm not happy with it because it implies many loops and objects creations in memory. Thank you anyway.

Comment: No loops are used if you just want to group them together, I was unsure from your question if they must be a certain order or if grouping was enough. You can't get away from looping if they must be a certain order. And you didn't show us the looping solution that you mentioned. Ok, you can get away without looping if you add a sorting reference, like you said, but you didn't want to do that either.