# Is there a way to map an array of objects given a reference array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I am currently trying to sort an array of objects in the same order of a given reference array. Anyone have a good performance based solution? Here is an example below...

```
let example = () => {
    let referenceArray = ['name', 'date', 'creator','description'];

    let orderObject = [
        {type:'txt',orderBy:'date'},
        {type:'txt',orderBy:'name'},
        {type:'txt',orderBy:'description'},
        {type:'txt',orderBy:'creator'}
    ];

    // code to sort object here?

}
```

EDIT: Looks like I was able to implement a solution. With the code below I was able to map the object to have the same order as the array.

```
let example = () => {
    let referenceArray = ['name', 'date', 'creator','description'];
    let copy = [];
    let orderObject = [
        {type:'txt',orderBy:'date'},
        {type:'txt',orderBy:'name'},
        {type:'txt',orderBy:'description'},
        {type:'txt',orderBy:'creator'}
    ];

    // code to sort object here?
    orderObject.forEach((x) => {
        let index = referenceArray.indexOf(x.orderBy);
        copy.splice(index,0,x);
    });
}
```

Comment: Sort in what manner? Can you show a realistic example of input and the expected output? Do you want to sort the object by the `orderBy` field using the order determined by the array? If you want that, don't use the `referenceArray`, instead use an object that maps strings to numbers representing the order.

Comment: _I am currently trying to sort.._ Show what you've tried.

Comment: Hello, it is unclear what you are asking. What is the expected input and output of what you're trying to accomplish? What have you tried? What have you looked up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - sort Array by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135485/javascript-sort-array-by-reference)

Comment: @Shidersz you are under the correct assumption, i do want to sort by the orderBy field using the order of the referenceArray. I don't want to create another object seeing that i am being passed this array. But from what you possible answer was, would that be the quickest way?

Comment: @JakeWorth I will see if this is applicable. looks promising

Comment: sorting was not the correct term, i mean mapping

Comment: @DanielTurcich refer to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like I was able to implement my own solution.

```
let example = () => {
    let referenceArray = ['name', 'date', 'creator','description'];
    let copy = [];
    let orderObject = [
        {type:'txt',orderBy:'date'},
        {type:'txt',orderBy:'name'},
        {type:'txt',orderBy:'description'},
        {type:'txt',orderBy:'creator'}
    ];

    // code to sort object here?
    orderObject.forEach((x) => {
        let index = referenceArray.indexOf(x.orderBy);
        copy.splice(index,0,x);
    });
}
```